# match key of hash and then fetch values accordingly in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have included the given code:

```
@classes = {1=>"USA", 3=>"France", 2=>"UK",  5=>"Europe", 7=>"Delhi", 8=>"test"}
@amaze = params[:test]  #I get "1,3,7"
```

I get this, now please guide me how to match keys with `@amaze` and accordingly fetch its values from `@classes` i.e USA, France, Delhi.

Comment: is `@amaze` an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@amaze` is just a String, lets first convert it in Array so its easy to enumerate:

```
@amaze = "1,3,7"
@amaze = @amaze.split(",")
# => ["1", "3", "7"]
```

Now, since you have all keys extract all values:

```
@amaze.map { |i| @classes[i.to_i] }
# => ["USA", "France", "Delhi"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split `@amaze` by `,` and get an array of keys, convert them into Integer, then select only those key/value pairs which key is into this array of keys. Something like this:

```
@classes = {1=>"USA", 3=>"France", 2=>"UK",  5=>"Europe", 7=>"Delhi", 8=>"test"}
@amaze = "1,3,7"  #I get "1,3,7"
arr = @amaze.split(',').map(&:to_i)
p @classes.select{|el| arr.include? el}
```

Result:

```
#> {1=>"USA", 3=>"France", 7=>"Delhi"}
```

If you want values only use `.values`:

```
p @classes.select{|el| arr.include? el}.values
```

Result:

```
#> ["USA", "France", "Delhi"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what(seemingly) you are asking, the below line will do it:

```
@amaze.split(",").each { |i| p @classes[i.to_i] }

# If @amaza = "1,3,7", above line will output:
# => "USA"
#    "France"
#    "UK"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a clearer understanding of hashes would help you out here.

A `Hash` is a data structure that is a list of key-value pairs. For example, the following is a Hash object of key-value pairs (your example):

```
@classes = {1=>"USA", 3=>"France", 2=>"UK",  5=>"Europe", 7=>"Delhi", 8=>"test"}
```

If you want to extract a value from `@classes`, you need to pass the key of the value you want. If we wanted `"USA"` we would pass the key of `1` to `@classes`. If we wanted `"France"`, we would pass it the key of `3`:

`@classes[1]` would return `"USA"` and `@classes[3]` would return `"France"`.

It's not clear what data structure `@amaze` is according to your question, but let's say it's the string `"1, 3, 7"` which we can split to create an array `[1, 3, 7]`.

You could iterate over the array to get each of the values from `@classes`:

```
@amaze.split(",").map(&:to_i).each do |key|
  puts @classes[key]
end
```

That would print out each of the corresponding values to keys in `@classes`.

Comment: This will not work as the keys are integers and split produces strings. change to `@classes[key.to_i]` or `@amaze.split(',').map(&:to_i).each`

Answer (score 0):

This should work well for you:

```
@classes = {1=>"USA", 3=>"France", 2=>"UK",  5=>"Europe", 7=>"Delhi", 8=>"test"}
@amaze = params[:test].split(",").map(&:to_i) 
@classes.values_at(*@amaze)
#=> ["USA", "France", "Delhi"]
```

`Hash#values_at` accepts an indefinite number of keys and returns their values as an array. The `*` (splat) operator explodes the array so this call actually becomes `@classes.values_at(1,3,7)`  [Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)

Might also want to add a `compact` to the end in the event a key does not exist. e.g

```
@amaze = params[:test].split(",").map(&:to_i) # Asssume this returns [1,3,7,9]
@classes.values_at(*@amaze)
#=> ["USA", "France", "Delhi",nil]
@classes.values_at(*@amaze).compact
#=> ["USA", "France", "Delhi"]
```